# PHP method to perform AES encryption block-by-block to conserve memory usage

Tags: php, memory-management, encryption, cryptography, aes

Let me explain my dilemma. In my PHP script I need to be able to encrypt files uploaded to my site. I chose to use [AES-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) encryption with CBC ([Cipher-block chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29)) mode of operation.

Initially I discovered a very promising function that could do this, that would've worked like this:

```
//Just the encryption part
$fileData = file_get_contents($serverFilePath);
$encData = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $binKey,
            $fileData,
            MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, 
            $binIV);
```

The method above works well, except one major issue: I host my site on a shared hosting account and as you see the `mcrypt_encrypt` method requires the data to be fed into it *all at once* as a *binary string*. That becomes an issue if the file that I'm encrypting is sufficiently large. In which case the `mcrypt_encrypt` fails, my script is terminated and the user sees a blank white page... oops!

After that I get the following message in the error_log:

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate Y bytes) in blah-blah

Obviously, by running on a shared host my script does not have all the available RAM, but even if it had access to more RAM, there may still be a situation when the size of the file being encrypted exceeds all available RAM, needed to load its contents into a binary string.

(By the way, the method above fails when I try to encrypt just a 200 MB file, which is not that big by today's standards.)

Thus my question/dilemma:

Is there a method to perform AES encryption on just one block of plaintext (without CBC or any other mode of operation, just plain-old AES) and if so I can [do CBC myself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0D7OwYp6ZEc)? If yes, I can write my own method by encrypting block-by-block and thus avoid the pitfall of the `mcrypt_encrypt` function and not load the whole file into RAM.

Any suggestions would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate a single AES block encryption by simply using the ECB mode for `mcrypt_encrypt` instead of CBC mode and then doing CBC yourself. The ECB mode is essentially stateless. There is no propagation from the last encrypted block like in CBC mode. It is just applying AES on each block separately.

Depending on how you do the stream reading, it might be easier or more performant to use chunks of CBC encryption. You can still use your method on chunks of the file to encrypt. You would then use the last ciphertext block as the IV for the next chunk.

Comment: @c00000fd I'm not going to post code. If you implement it, feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: I'm trying to come up with one. I'm more of a C/C++ coder, and PHP is somewhat "funky" to implement crypto methods. I'll post my version when I have it.